# Android NDK C++ error : 'memmove' was not declared in this scope

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk

In android ndk c++ in visual studio, I'm trying to use memmove.

The compiler throws:

> error : 'memmove' was not declared in this scope, and no declarations were found by argument-dependent lookup at the point of instantiation

I include *string.h* so, I don't get what I am missing here...
I inspected the string.h and found that the definition of memmove in string.h in the ndk is inside a preprocessor block

`#if defined(__BIONIC_FORTIFY)`

And is undefined.

I don't know what is this preprocessor and why it is preventing the memmove from being defined.

What is this __BIONIC_FORTIFY thing? is it safe to define?
Is there a problem using memmove in android?

My research : this preprocessor is defined by

`#define _FORTIFY_SOURCE`

but adding this to my build does not get rid of the error.

Comment: Which ndk version are you using?

Comment: im using Android Tegra NDK r12b in Visual Studio 2015

Comment: That is quite an old one. Can you check if there is any difference if you switch to r15c and r18b?

Comment: Ok, my fault, i changed to r16 and the problem dissapeared, but now I have others.

Comment: Can you try that with r15? r16-18 have major changes compared to 15th.

Comment: @DmitriiZ. after a hell of a week of reinstalling Visual Studio 2015, 2017 , Codeworks 1R7, 1R5 etc, I made it work in 1R5. Thank you!